# @Tag("myTestName") not working with Groovy test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock, junit5

I have java and groovy tests in the project. I would like to split tests into groups.

For this I am trying to use @Tag annotation on class level.

For java classes it works perfectly but Groovy classes seem to be not affected by @Tag annotation at all.

Junit version: **junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0**

Spock version **1.1-groovy-2.4**

Groovy version: **groovy-all:2.4.15**

Java version: **8**

```
package com.myproject.service

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag
import spock.lang.Specification

@Tag("MyTestGroup")
class MyTest extends Specification {

    def 'test me'() {
        expect:
        1 == 5
    }
}
```

And in build.gradle:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        excludeTags 'MyTestGroup'
    }
}

tasks.register("MyTestGroup", Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags 'MyTestGroup'
    }
    check.dependsOn it
    MyTestGroup.shouldRunAfter test
}
```

And I run tests using: **./gradlew check**

Does anybody know how to make @Tag working with Groovy files?

Comment: Please include the entire `MyTest.groovy` file with imports and all.

Comment: But where should I include it? I don't specify specific tests anywhere for now. Where would I put it?

Comment: Oh you meant my file. Ok done

Comment: As far as I am aware, Spock 1 works only with JUnit 4; you might need to try `@Category` instead.